# Как сделать чтобы при присваивании значений переменной в блоке try, это значение оставалось при вылете в catch?

Tags: sql, sql-server, try-catch

В блоке Try у меня огромный запрос на добавление данных в таблицу(из других таблиц), после чего я пишу

```
set @insertingRows = @@ROWCOUNT
```

И после, если произошла ошибка в добавлении и вылетело в catch, мне необходимо вывести сколько строк было затронуто (как раз для этого я ввела переменную).

Если это можно сделать по другому, то как?

---

```
begin tran
  begin try

    insert into (...)
    set @insertingRows = @@ROWCOUNT
    insert into tpLog(logMsg) values ('Inserting: '+@insertingRows)
    commit
  end try

  begin catch
    insert into tpLog(logMsg) values 
       ('ALL: '+@allRows+ ' | Error inserting: '+@insertingRows+ 
       ' | Error line: '+ERROR_LINE()+ ' | Error message: '+ERROR_MESSAGE());
    throw;
    rollback
  end catch
```

Comment: может переменная не видна в этой области видимости? приведите больше кода, чтоб это было понятно. Да и проблему тоже не написали.

Comment: @4per добавила код

Comment: При ошибке вставки всегда будет затронуто 0 строк, так как операция [атомарная](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). Т. е. либо все записи вносятся, либо нет. Если прям нужна частичная вставка попробуйте пройтись циклом по одной записи.

Comment: @Полинochk4 а если в блоке CATCH использовать @@ROWCOUNT?